# MYSQL Select MAX Value and Delete

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my script that logs transactions and each transaction is given a unique ID number( a auto increment) and I would like to select the highest transaction ID row and delete it. I had something like

```
SELECT * FROM trans WHERE (Select MAX(tranID)FROM Trans);
```

To get the information and

```
DELETE FROM Trans WHERE (SELECT MAX(trainID));
```

To delete it.

Now these work but they select everything and delete every entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have no `FROM` clause in the subquery. A non-zero value it returns will be misconstrued as boolean true, matching _all rows_. You mean to do something like `WHERE something = (SELECT MAX(trainID) FROM Trans)`

Comment: @MichealBerkowski I had a From clause inside and I got "You Can't Specify target table 'Trans' for update in From clause. That's why I left out.

Comment: right - I was just running a test to get the exact error message you'd get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL supports a `LIMIT` for `DELETE` queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).  Rather than attempting to get the `MAX(trainID)` which you have found leads to errors when done with a subquery, specify the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
DELETE FROM Trans
ORDER BY trainID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It should alternatively work to join against a subquery instead of trying to use it in the `WHERE`:

```
DELETE t.*
FROM 
  Trans t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(trainID) maxt FROM Trans) tmax ON t.trainID = tmax.maxt
```

[Here are both version in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67ea0/1)

Yours deletes all rows because `(SELECT MAX(trainID))` evaluates as a boolean `TRUE`, which matches all rows

Comment: @MichealBerkowski with your first query how would I go about putting in a where clause to make it even more specific? I want to delete the highest ID but I want to make sure it's the specifics customers transaction. Sorry should of said originally.

Comment: @Softey You can just add a where clause. `DELETE FROM Trans WHERE customer = 123 ORDER BY trainID DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

> Now these work but they select everything and delete every entry.

In this query :

```
DELETE FROM Trans WHERE (SELECT MAX(trainID));
```

After process will result to :

```
DELETE FROM Trans WHERE (true);
```

hence this is equal to => `DELETE FROM Trans` and thats why all your table data is deleted!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Trans WHERE trainId = (SELECT MAX(trainID) FROM Trans );
```